# Styling JSON pages

Tags: html, css, json, api

I'm working on a JSON API and I want to do something like Facebook's [opengraph](http://graph.facebook.com/4) styling.
The opengraph style indents and breaks lines, how do you go about doing this? If you use styling through HTML or CSS the JSON can not be loaded.

Comment: so what is your question?  Browsers style json differently, depending on which one you are using and if you have JSON plugins installed.

Comment: "The opengraph style indents and breaks lines, how do you go about doing this?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JSON_PRETTY_PRINT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which is new in [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php):

```
<?php 

// Facebook sends a Content-Type of text/javascript
// So I assume you want to too, but you may prefer
// application/json
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

If you don't have, or can't upgrade to version 5.4 then you have to find some side of server-side parser.

**Edit**

I don't know why I assumed you're using PHP when you haven't tagged it. Whatever server side language you're using though you'll want to send out a non-html Content-Type and use new lines and tabs to pretty print it, not HTML.

Comment: You assumed correctly, I don't know why I didn't tag it myself.

Comment: @Jake Alright, cool :) Do you have 5.4 or the ability to upgrade? It was just released as stable this month.

Comment: I have the ability only on my local development version of my site.

Comment: @Jake in that case check this post for a user function json pretty printer: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#80339

Comment: <pre> to the resque to keep whitespace in HTML too.

Comment: @sg3s that would make it so the JSON wouldn't load properly.

Comment: Depends on the context, if you want to show the pretty print inside a html document you will have to use <pre> or something similar.

Comment: @sg3s seems like when FireFox and Chrome read a document with Content-Type text/javascript, they automatically add the `<pre>` tags to the DOM. Not sure what other Content-Types they do this for though.

Comment: @sg3s JSON is *always* valid Javascript :)

Answer (score 3):

facebook appear to be using browser detection to format the JSON on the server.

for wget, no formatting is applied:

```
> wget -q -S -O - http://graph.facebook.com/4
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
  Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
  ETag: "539feb8aee5c3d20a2ebacd02db380b27243b255"
  Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
  P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-FB-Rev: 526949
  Set-Cookie: datr=imJrT4lrhBZ48Mrtw4uYfByk; expires=Sat, 22-Mar-2014 17:34:02 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
  X-FB-Debug: +gpBLnliDoRvuNtlHIwHASwsDz4pJm9TP3btrrw6AsE=
  X-Cnection: close
  Date: Thu, 22 Mar 2012 17:34:02 GMT
  Content-Length: 172
{"id":"4","name":"Mark Zuckerberg","first_name":"Mark","last_name":"Zuckerberg","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/zuck","username":"zuck","gender":"male","locale":"en_US"}
```

but for google chrome, wireshark shows text formatted with spaces and newlines:

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

(it really is different data - the Content-Length is 210 in this case).  note that Content-Type is still text/javascript - they are not rendering into HTML.

so you'd need to use a JSON formatter for whatever language you are using (i guess you are already using a library, so check whether it has a "prettyprint" option or similar).  plus, if you want to save bandwidth when formatting seems unimportant, browser (and general context - see Paul's comment) detection from request headers.

Comment: Looks like they detect your User-Agent and pretty print for browsers, but probably not for requests from within their JS API or CURL requests. Since most requests directly by browsers are probably actually developers that want to read it, it makes sense.

Comment: yep; referenced you above :o)